# Python ctypes segmentation fault when rootfs is read-only and /tmp is noexec

Tags: python, python-2.7, segmentation-fault, ctypes, cpython

I'm trying to use Python for an embedded app on an Arm processor running Linux (CPython 2.7.3 cross-compiled from X86/Linux). It worked really well until I started securing the device to prevent tampering. First I made the rootfs read-only, both to prevent corruption of the rootfs on a sudden loss of power and to prevent modification to our main code by unauthorized users. Still, python and our ctypes libraries continued working as normal. The /tmp directory gets mapped to a tmpfs (ramdrive). Another step of hardening is to set the noexec flag on the tmpfs partition to prevent users from somehow uploading any code that could lead to a local root exploit. With both of those options set, importing ctypes produces an immediate segfault:

```
root@ATX4:~# python                                 
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 16 2013, 17:15:57) 
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
Segmentation fault
```

Interestingly enough, any of the changes below allows ctypes to work correctly:

1. Remounting the rootfs as read-write
2. Remounting the tmpfs without noexec
3. Remounting /dev/shm without noexec

Any idea what's causing this? For now, I've made /dev/shm mount without noexec, and just restrict it to the least possible users.

Comment: Importing ctypes calls [`_reset_cache`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py#l265), which creates a callback. Skipping along, [`_ctypes_alloc_callback`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c#l408) calls libffi `ffi_closure_alloc`. Look at [Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/closures.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/closures.c).

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint on `ffi_closure_alloc`, `dlmmap`, and `dlmmap_locked`? I think you're ending up in the latter, which iterates through the array of options [`open_temp_exec_file_opts`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/closures.c#l313).

Comment: Can you still reproduce the problem? If so, can you please post the contents of ``/proc/mounts`` on your device in the configuration where the crash occurs? ctypes/libffi parses that file, so maybe it crashes there.

Comment: Sadly, I'm no longer on that project and don't have access to the hardware to get that info.

Comment: This is tracked (and seems to be solved) in https://bugs.python.org/issue11048

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this with Python 2.7.6;

I suspect it could've been a valid bug.

Consider that ctypes may need to create a unique callback (an executable C-level function). It would `mmap` some anonymous (ok) or shared file (not ok) with execute bit set.

Memory error handling is always hard, and could have easily escaped developers.

Comment: Ran into this issue (or something very similar) with Python 2.7.7